# Insert and delete data in table using before insert trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created a trigger which inserts the last record of conversation table in `conversation_h` table, and delete that record from `conversation` using before insert event.

Any other logic or code is also welcome but i want achieve the above using trigger only.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `transfer_data` BEFORE INSERT 
    ON `conversation`

    FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

if  (select count(*) from `conversation`) > 2
then 

  set @mid = (select id from conversation order by id asc limit 0,1);

insert into conversation_h select * from conversation where id=@mid;

delete from conversation where id=@mid;


    END IF;

    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Is there actually a question in there? I only see facts stated. If you have a problem with the shown code (as the answer suggests) then please post the problems there are with it here next time

Comment: Yes this question.  "delete from conversation where id=@mid ";  is not working, And when i delete this line then above trigger is working fine.

Comment: and again, "is not working" is not a proper description. what happens? are there any error messages? if so, please mention them. this question seems answered, yes? just something to keep in mind for next question

Comment: Above trigger is created succesfully , but when i insert data in conversation table then there is an error  " Can't update table 'conversation' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. "

Answer (score 0):

[This is not possible with triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> A (...) trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the (...) trigger.

Comment: there is any way to delete record from table using trigger?