# Restricting max no of rows insert in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create a table which should contain max of 5 rows, when ever there is a 6th insert operation the last row must be deleted.

I want max of 5 rows and I want to do this in SQLIte database in android.

please suggest me a query which is simple.

Comment: This type of operation is normally handled by an insert trigger.  I don't know if that is "simple".

Comment: can you tell me one example of insert trigger in SQLite bro :)

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the question appears to be about SQLite.

Comment: Yo @GordonLinoff thanks for that bro.... and please suggest me a easy way to solve this issue bro :)

Comment: Just have a row ID field.  Insert 5 initial entries with row IDs 1-5.  Then use a counter that counts to 5 and then back to 1.  Update your rows by row ID, based on the counter.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "last row"?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a row count in your application. If it returns more than four, or eaqual to five, rows you delete the last row before inserting a new one.

UPDATE:
I did a bit of testing on a table which i named `test_table`, and added this trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `schema_name`.`trigger_name` BEFORE INSERT ON `database_name`.`test_table`
FOR EACH ROW

if (select count(*) from test_table)> 4  /*  count records to see if it exeeds your limit  */
    then 
        delete from test_table where id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM test_table LIMIT 1);  /*  delete last row  */
END if;
END
```

When I try to insert a sixth row I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'test_table' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I looked it up and found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21117071/1355562 - which lead me to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html.
The section "Restrictions for Stored Functions", point 5, says "... cannot modify a table that is already being used..."

Looks like you have to do this in you application bro ;)

ops.. just noticed you're working an MySQLlite.. Maybe it's different. This was for MySQL... Sorry about that...

Comment: have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963694/mysql-trigger-to-delete-old-record-and-insert-new-one. It might give you the answer you're seeking